# Huge checkpoint size using ValueState leading to event processing lag

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an application in flink, which does deduplication of multiple streams.
It does key-by on one string field and dedupes it by using value-state.

Using value state in RichFilterFunction.

```
public class DedupeWithState extends RichFilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Message>> {
    private ValueState<Boolean> seen;
    private final ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc;

    public DedupeWithState(long cacheExpirationTimeMs) {
        StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
                .newBuilder(Time.milliseconds(cacheExpirationTimeMs))
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
                .build();
        desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        desc.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration conf) {
        seen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Message> stringMessageTuple2) throws Exception {
        if (seen.value() == null) {
            seen.update(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The application consumes 3 streams from kafka, and each stream has its own dedupe function with ttl of 4hours.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Message>> event1 = event1Input
                .keyBy(x->x.f0)
                .filter(new DedupeWithState(14400000));
                
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Message>> event2 = event2Input
                .keyBy(x->x.f0)
                .filter(new DedupeWithState(14400000));

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Message>> event3 = event3Input
                .keyBy(x->x.f0)
                .filter(new DedupeWithState(14400000));
```

Screenshots attached.

Backend properties are:

```
state.backend: rocksdb
state.backend.incremental: true
state.checkpoints.dir: <azure blob store>
```

[Checkpoint configuration as on WebUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJlD6.png)

- We are using Flink 1.13.6.
- The QPS of each stream is event1 - 7k, event2 - 6k, event3 - 200
- Key size is ~110 bytes
- Checkpoint interval is 5 mins and incremental checkpoint is enabled.
  As per above configs (given that incremental checkpoint is enabled) each stream should have following checkpoint size:
  event1 -> ((7000 * 60 * 5) * 110bytes) = ~220MB

**Issue is the checkpoint size is very huge. It starts from 400 MB (as expected) but is going upto 2-3GB per checkpoint [Checkpoint history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xfAV.png). This results in huge backpressure in Dedupe function and overall lag in the system. [Checkpoint per operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtqrK.png)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the state is not being cleaned since it is done lazily (on read). From the initial release [post](https://flink.apache.org/2019/05/19/state-ttl.html) (a bit old but may still stand):

> When a state object is accessed in a read operation, Flink will check its timestamp and clear the state if it is expired (depending on the configured state visibility, the expired state is returned or not). Due to this lazy removal, expired state that is never accessed again will forever occupy storage space unless it is garbage collected.

I would try with a `MapState` per stream (without keying by) instead of a `ValueState` per key as you have now so the same state is continuously accessed. Or you may also be able to set up a timer in `DedupeWithState` that accesses the state and forces the cleanup (you may need to use a `ProcessFunction` to be able to set up timers) or that simply clears it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
/**
 * @author sucheth.shivakumar
 */
public class Check extends KeyedProcessFunction {
    private ValueState<Boolean> seen;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        // defines the time the state has to be stored in the state backend before it is auto cleared
        seen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void processElement(Object value, Context ctx, Collector out) throws Exception {
        if (seen.value() == null) {
            seen.update(true);
            // emits the record
            out.collect(stringMessageTuple2);
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + 14400000);
        }
    }
    
    
    @Override
    // this fires after 4 hrs is passed and clears the state
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector out)
            throws Exception {
        // triggers after ttl has passed
        if (seen.value()) {
            seen.clear();
        }
    }
```